# Can I use captured alien weapons?

Tags: xenonauts

I just finished my first crash site mission and recovered 3 plasma rifles. However, I don't see them as available to equip on the soldiers in my base. Is there a way I can use captured enemy weapons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to using alien tech you need to [research](http://xenonauts.wikia.com/wiki/Research) it. Quote:

In order to start a research project you simply need to select a project and let your scientists get to work. However in order to start the research you need the following.

1. A research project.
2. A Laboratory.
3. Scientists.

You will also need any minimum resources needed to start the project, if the project needs any prior resources, for example researching an Alien weapon requires you have that weapon in your stores.

Answer (score 2):

Yet, you can not use alien weapons, even after you research them.  But you can do so during a mission.  Just walk over a dead alien and grab his gun :)
There seems to be some accuracy penalties, when using alien weapons though.

Comment: Severe penalties - but there's hardly a more satisfying ending for a terror mission, when a Rocketeer who'd ran out of rockets picks up an alien rifle from a corpse and kills the last xeno scum with it.